# Как сделать хп врага?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Шалом. У меня появилась проблема.

1. С помощью какого скрипта добавить урон от выстрелов? (и куда его добавить)
2. Как сделать XP у врагов?.
3. Как сделать хр у себя?

ПОЖАЛУЙСТА ОБЬЯСНЯЙТЕ ПОДРОБНО ИБО Я ТОЛЬКО НАЧАЛ Изучать.

Comment: Эти проблемы вам только кажутся, на самом деле наиболее вероятные проблемы - это "я пока не знаю C#" и "я пока не знаком с Unity". Продолжайте изучать, на определенном этапе вышеуказанные вопросы вам покажутся вполне решаемыми.

Answer (score 1):

Хп храните как число от 0 до 100 например. Когда пуля пересекает персонажа отнимаете какое-то количество. У себя или у врагов неважно.

Answer (score 1):

Знаете про [`Принципы SOLID`](https://web-creator.ru/articles/solid)? Это сокращение. Нам интересует буква `S` который гласит:

> Для каждого класса должно быть определено единственное назначение. Все ресурсы, необходимые для его осуществления, должны быть инкапсулированы в этот класс и подчинены только этой задаче.

---

Следуя принципу:

1. Создаём скрипт `Data` или `Database`. Там будут буквально ВСЕ данные об игре - количество врагов, имя главного героя, любимое блюдо главного героя, количество жизней и так далее. Там всё должно быть публичное чтобы менять данные с других скриптов.
2. Каждый элемент должен иметь свой скрипт, который будет контролировать взаимодействие именно с ним. Это не значит создать 3141592 скриптов, надо всё это делать аккуратно.
3. Вам крайне будут полезна [информация о событиях и обработчиках в Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2018.4/Manual/UnityEvents.html) чтобы весь код не вложить в `Update`

---

А теперь маленький пример:

- Data.cs

```cs
public static class Player
{
    private static int _MinHealth = 0, _MaxHealth = 100, _Health = 100;
    public static int Health
    {
        get  
        {  
            return _Health;
        }  
        set  
        {  
            if(value < _MinHealth)
            {
                _Health = _MinHealth;
            }
            else if(value > _MaxHealth)
            {
                _Health = _MaxHealth;
            }
            else
            {
                _Health = value;
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

- Player.cs

```cs
private void OnColliderEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
    {
        Data.Player.Health -= Random.Range(20, 30);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        if(Data.Player.Health == 0)
        {
            Destroy(this);
            Debug.Log("Проигрыш.");
        }
    }
    else if(other.gameObject.tag == "Medkit")
    {
        Data.Player.Health += 25;
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        Debug.Log("ОЗ восстановлено на 25 очков.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вся информация будет в одной БД, то могут быть проблемы со скоростью доступа к ней из-за большого количества запросов

Comment: @dIm0n Я всегда так делал, пока не было никаких проблем.

Comment: Человек не знает даже, что такое переменная, а в ему про `solid`. Тут даже `метать бисер перед свиньями` не подойдёт, скорее алмазы.

Comment: @Yaroslav ну тут я ему помочь уже не смогу. Пусть учит C# - https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/

Comment: С каких пор "класс со всеми открытыми полями, чтобы другие объекты могли его изменять" является валидным в отношении принципов SOLID?